# dart label control- not understanding the flow

Tags: dart

Consider the following `dart` code:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  firstLoop:
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    print('${i}::I am in the first loop');

    secondLoop:
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      print('${j}::I am in the second loop.');

      thirdLoop:
      for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        print('${k}::I am in the third loop');

        fourthLoop:
        for (var l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
          print('${l}::I am in the fourth loop');
          break secondLoop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output was:

```
0::I am in the first loop
0::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
1::I am in the first loop
0::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
```

And for the following code:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  firstLoop:
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    print('${i}::I am in the first loop');

    secondLoop:
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      print('${j}::I am in the second loop.');

      thirdLoop:
      for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        print('${k}::I am in the third loop***');

        fourthLoop:
        for (var l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
          print('${l}::I am in the fourth loop');
          break thirdLoop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output was:

```
0::I am in the first loop
0::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
1::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
1::I am in the first loop
0::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
1::I am in the second loop.
0::I am in the third loop***
0::I am in the fourth loop
```

I can't really understand this  flow.
The behaviour is like:

> when I jump to a certain label, the statement or block above that label is executed?

It doesn't look like my understanding is clear. Please give me more insight/clearance to this.

Comment: I think you have some problems with your first example. The code could not have generated that output.

Comment: @julemand101 , I'm sorry, I copied the same output twice

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what part you think is absurd since it's not clear what behavior you expect. If you expect `break thirdLoop` to jump to the `thirdLoop` label, you're mixing up `break thirdLoop` with `continue thirdLoop`. `break thirdLoop` instead would break out of the loop labeled with `thirdLoop`.

Comment: so `break secondLoop` for example means to break through the second loop and not break the current loop and jump to the second loop label?

Comment: Yes, `break secondLoop` would break out of the second loop, thereby jumping to the next iteration of the first loop.

Answer (score 4):

When you break a labeled statement, whether it's a loop or not, it behaves as if that statement had just completed normally (not throwing, not returning, not any other control flow).

A labeled statement is something of the form `label: statement`. The statement doesn't have to be a loop, but it usually is.

So, if you write:

```dart
print("outside before");
label: {
  print("inside before");
  break label; // Breaks to *end of labeled statement*.
  print("inside after");
} // End of labeled statement is here.
print("outside after");
```

it will print:

```
outside before
inside before
outside after
```

You can break *any* statement, as long as you can refer to it.
A `break` with no label automatically refers to the closest enclosing loop or `switch` statement. If you want to break to break any other statement, you need to give it a name with a label first, so you can do `break label;` to designate the statement to break.

(You can also have labels on the `case`s of a `switch`. You *cannot* break those because they are not statements, you have to break the `switch` instead.)

In your example, you are breaking a loop which is also the *last* statement of an outer loop. When you break the inner loop, you reach the end of the body of the outer loop, and it goes on to the next iteration (if it has one). That's why it looks like it is going backwards, it's hitting the end of the loop and looping backwards, just as loops normally do.

So, `break` does not jump to a label, it *exits* the labeled statement.

If you want to *continue* with that label, you may want to use `continue label;` instead. Continuing a loop means going back to the loop header and (maybe) take another iteration of the loop. It works precisely as *breaking out of the body* of the loop. You end the body, then the normal loop behavior takes over.

Example:

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  print("before: $i");
  if (i.isEven) continue;
  print("after: $i");
}
```

This prints:

```
before: 0
before: 1
after: 1
before: 2
before: 3
after: 3
before: 4
```

It works with all kinds of loops, even `do`-`while`:

```dart
var i = 0;
do {
  print("before: $i");
  if (i.isEven) continue;
  print("after: $i");
} while (++i < 5);
```

prints the same thing.